# signup ,signin and Share content via linkedin and twitter with server side auth (like google+)?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, linkedin-api

Please share signup ,signin and Share content via linkedin and twitter with server side auth (like google+).
Now I m using oneall api to do this.But I want to do using twitters ,linkedins api's.Thanks

Comment: No.In html page by passing dynamic values

Comment: Then go to the developers website of the respected network and then read api and try them;

Comment: Sometime users mark questions and answer negative unnecessarily. This is not good.

Answer (score -1):

Please check below link, this will help you. There are many demos with code.

http://demo.phpgang.com/

http://www.sitepoint.com/social-logins-php-hybridauth/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233651/looking-for-a-standalone-and-open-source-social-login-php-library

social share plugin js

http://www.addthis.com/academy/sharing-button-api-overview/

paypal api

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/
http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/paypal-php-integration

Comment: Thanks @Deepak Dholiyan. I will check out above links.Can you please give few payment gateways tutorials.

Comment: which payment gateway you want to implement?

Comment: Paypal Payment gateway

Comment: All above sharing demos are in php . Please help to implement in jquery/javascript

Comment: Thanks @Deepak Can u plz help me to implement paypal payment gateway. I have a issue regarding it, After completion of payment the paypal account should signout automatically but its not logging out ,whenever I closed browser then only its logged out.

Comment: @Rupesh, I am busy.  
if you satisfied with answer accept and upvote. – Deepak Dholiyan 2 days ago

Comment: Sorry @deepak your solution is in php but I want in jquery or javascript. And can u plz help me to fix paypal bug as I explained above

Comment: @Rupesh, This is jquery plugin

Comment: addthis.com/academy/sharing-button-api-overview